# Kendo grid two filtering modes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid on a page. I added the filtering possibility like this for every column
I need to add the row filtering of the kendo grid, and it looks like this.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GGISServices.Models.DistrictViewModel>()
    .Name("districtGrid")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "newGrid" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
     columns.Bound(c => c.NatureOfProduct).Title(LanguageService.Instance.Translate("NatureOfProduct")).Filterable(f => f.Multi(true).DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Action("GetFilterData", "Contract", new { Area = GGISWeb.AreaModules.District }).Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("{ field: 'NatureOfProduct' }"))));
```

This filter looks like this, and the user can select more than one item to search
 [image]

But I needed to change to row filtering mode, because the client asked for search box for every column, so I added

```
 .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
```

and now the filer appears like this

[image]

which is ok, this is what the client needs, but they want both searching possibilities, and when I have added the

```
  .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
```

the filter where I can select all items does not appear anymore. 
Can you please advise how to do, to show both filter: the searchbox for every column and the other where the user can select the items?
Or if I use only the  `GridFilterMode.Row` the user has the posssibility to select more than one item?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the

```
  .ColumnMenu(f => f.Enabled(true))
```

and for the columns

```
   .Filterable(f => f.Multi(true));
```